# How to set a custom object value in angular ng-options?

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I have a array `opts` with the different options for a `<select>` element. Array's objects have a property `text` for display and a property `value` for get the value and set in a variable `$scope.opt2`.

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.opts = [
        {value: 10, text: '1st' },
        {value: 20, text: '2nd' }
    ];
}
```

I want set:

- `$scope.opt2 = {ref: 10}` and show `1st` when the first option is selected
- `$scope.opt2 = {ref: 20}` and show `2nd` when the second option is selected

I tried:

```
<select ng-model="opt2" ng-options="{ref: obj.value} as obj.text for obj in opts">
```

The value sets correctly but the `text` is not show. Any solution?

Examples for testing: http://codepen.io/ces/pen/azbLzX

Comment: sorry, it's still unclear for me what you want to do

Comment: You can't do a binding like that, is [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEOGqY) what you want to achieve?

Comment: I edited the question with a example. I hope that is more clear. Yes Philipp, that's is. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Philipps response will work, it's a little more complicated then you need it to be, change your select to this:

```
<select ng-model="opt2.ref" ng-options="obj.value as obj.text for obj in opts">
```

See the edited codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJWeVQ